# Creando un arducky con HoodLoader2 (problemas al subir el sketch "installation_sketch.ino")

Tags: arduino

estoy intentando crear un arducky, estuve leyendo algunas páginas en las que se hablaba de como crearlo y empecé a seguir las instrucciones 
(
https://kr0no.me/post/2016/10/usb-rubber-ducky-arduino

https://blog.kalrong.net/es/2017/05/30/como-instalar-hoodloader2-y-convertir-nuestro-arduino-en-un-rubber-ducky/

http://www.elladodelmal.com/2017/07/arducky-un-rubber-ducky-hecho-sobre.html
)

Cuando intenté subir el sketch de instalación de HoodLoader2 a mi Arduino UNO, el IDE de Arduino soltó un mensaje diciendo que habían problemas al subir el sketch a la placa, les dejo el mensaje de error (espero que alguien pueda ayudar):

```
Arduino:1.8.5 (Windows 8.1), Tarjeta:"Arduino/Genuino Uno"

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino:462:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

 };  // end of signatures

 ^

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino:462:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino:462:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino:462:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino:462:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino:462:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino:462:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino:462:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino:462:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino:462:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino:462:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino:462:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino:462:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino:462:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino:462:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino:462:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino:462:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino:462:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino:462:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino:462:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino:462:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino:462:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino:462:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino:462:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino:462:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino:462:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino:462:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino:462:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino:462:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino:462:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino:462:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino: In function 'void showHex(byte, boolean, boolean)':

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino:511:38: warning: narrowing conversion of '((((int)(b >> 4)) & 255) | 48)' from 'int' to 'char' inside { } [-Wnarrowing]

   char buf [4] = { ((b >> 4) & 0x0F) | '0', (b & 0x0F) | '0', ' ' , 0 };

                                      ^

C:\Users\PerezRomero\Desktop\HoodLoader2-master\avr\examples\Installation_Sketch\Installation_Sketch.ino:511:56: warning: narrowing conversion of '((((int)b) & 15) | 48)' from 'int' to 'char' inside { } [-Wnarrowing]

   char buf [4] = { ((b >> 4) & 0x0F) | '0', (b & 0x0F) | '0', ' ' , 0 };

                                                        ^

El Sketch usa 12488 bytes (38%) del espacio de almacenamiento de programa. El máximo es 32256 bytes.
Las variables Globales usan 1390 bytes (67%) de la memoria dinámica, dejando 658 bytes para las variables locales. El máximo es 2048 bytes.
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\\.\COM1": El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.


Problema subiendo a la placa. Visita http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload para sugerencias.

Este reporte podría tener más información con
"Mostrar salida detallada durante la compilación"
opción habilitada en Archivo -> Preferencias.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es bastante claro. Estás intentando comunicarte con un puerto que no existe. Lo que debes hacer es ir a Herramientas (*Tools*), Puerto(*Port*) y alli selecionar el puerto adecuado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]